# Remove files after recieving previews but before uploading to server using FileReader (HTML5)

Tags: javascript, html, filereader

I have a JavaScript function that shows me the previews of the images I want to upload to the server. After recieving that previews I can select some of them by clicking and remove previews, but I need also to remove the selected files so they will not be uploaded to the server.

The following code can remove the previews but not the files. How can it be improved?

JavaScript:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $("#image-holder").on('click', '.thumb-image', function () {
        $(this).toggleClass("selectedItem");
    });

    $("#btnDelete").on("click", function () {
        $(".selectedItem").remove();
    });

    $("#fileUpload").on('change', function () {
        //Get count of selected files
        var countFiles = $(this)[0].files.length;
        var imgPath = $(this)[0].value;
        var extn = imgPath.substring(imgPath.lastIndexOf('.') + 1).toLowerCase();
        var image_holder = $("#image-holder");
        image_holder.empty();
        if (extn == "gif" || extn == "png" || extn == "jpg" || extn == "jpeg") {
            if (typeof(FileReader) != "undefined") {
                //loop for each file selected for uploading.
                for (var i = 0; i < countFiles; i++) {
                    var reader = new FileReader();
                    reader.onload = function (e) {
                        $("<img />", {
                            "src": e.target.result,
                            "class": "thumb-image"
                        }).appendTo(image_holder);
                    };
                    image_holder.show();
                    reader.readAsDataURL($(this)[0].files[i]);
                }
            } else {
                alert("This browser does not support FileReader.");
            }
        } else {
            alert("Please select only images");
        }
    });
});
```

HTML:

```
<form method="POST" action="upload" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <input id="fileUpload" name="file" multiple="multiple" type="file"/>
        <br/>
        <input type="submit" value="Upload">
    </form>
    <button id="btnDelete">Delete</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

I've done this before using AngularJS. In that case I just had to set the `ng-model` variable to `undefined`. I haven't tested this, but you should be able to accomplish the same thing by clearing your `<input>` value in a similar way.

```
$("#btnDelete").on("click", function () {
    $(".selectedItem").remove();
    $("#fileUpload").get(0).files[0] = undefined;
    $("#fileUpload").removeAttr('value');
});
```

Comment: thank you for your answer, but it doesn't work this way.